# getting firebase campaign information from flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm writing a flutter app and I'm trying to find out how to fetch campaign information from the flutter app for the current user.

so In firebase console when I go to Conversions -> Network Settings
and I generate a Click campaign URL with some relevant values to `Source`, `Medium`, `Campaign`, `Ad Network Type` and `Creative`.

now when the user installed the app from that click campaign and executed the app, I want to be able from flutter to be able to fetch these parameters.

any ideas how to do so?

I thought i'll find it in the flutter analytics API but so far no luck.

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no public API to get the campaign information or other data from Google Analytics for Firebase.

The only ways to get analytics data from Firebase are:

- exporting the raw event data to BigQuery, and doing further/custom analysis there.
- exporting the data from the charts to CSV by clicking the <kbd>Download CSV</kbd> option from the <kbd>⠇</kbd> overflow menu.

As far as I know neither of these exports the definitions of your campaigns however. The best I can think of is to replicate the parameters in your app. I realize that's not ideal, so hope someone knows of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if in Feb. 2019, when @Frank van Puffelen first answered the question, there was already an official solution or not. I guess not because Puff is an Enginner at Firebase Google, so he would know.

However, I've studied about this subject to properly write a Wiki for my team in the aim of developing campaign tracking through GA4F (google analytics GA4 for Firebase) in a client's app.

I found this great article from Google itself: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142?sjid=12031628739701194152-SA#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

You'll also need these resources:

- https://pub.dev/packages/android_play_install_referrer/example
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download

  - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#troubleshoot-idfa

After everything is set up, you're ready to use Google URL builders to properly create your campaign URLs containing the needed parameters, which will be used by GA4F.

Bonus:

- I also read that the automatic event "firebase_campaign" does not appear on Firebase Events UI Console because it is only possible to be accessed using Big Query.
- Self-serve diagnosis for iOS conversion tracking
- If you do not see conversions for your iOS campaigns, follow these steps to troubleshoot:

  - Confirm iOS campaign tracking is enabled;
  - Confirm application ID matches;
  - Confirm GA SDK is sending the IDFA;
  - Look at the demographics report to confirm IDFA is being sent;
  - Ensure iOS campaign tracking URLs are correct.